# Linq compare hour

Tags: c#, linq, compare, hour

how can i compare hour in Linq ?

i use C# 4.0 and SQL Server 2008 R2.
my data:

```
CLIENT_ID (varchar) and HORRAIRE (time 7)
```

and my code :

```
IList<LS_CLIENTHORRAIRE> LesListe;
                using (Soft8Exp_ClientEntities oEntite_T = new Soft8Exp_ClientEntities())
                {
                    var query = from o in oEntite_T.LS_CLIENTHORRAIRE where o.CLIENT_ID == CLIENT_ID && o.HORRAIRE >= [the Computer Time] select o;
                    LesListe = query.ToList();
                }
                return LesListe;
```

Answer (score 1):

`time` data type in SQL [maps to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675168.aspx) `TimeSpan` in .Net, currently you want to compare it against current System time you may use:

```
DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
```

So your query would be:

```
var query = from o in oEntite_T.LS_CLIENTHORRAIRE 
            where o.CLIENT_ID == CLIENT_ID && o.HORRAIRE >= DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay 
            select o;
```

See: [DateTime.TimeOfDay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
o.HORRAIRE >= new TimeSpan(00/*hours*/, 00/*minutes*/, 00/*seconds*/)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int The_Hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
                    var query = from o in oEntite_T.LS_CLIENTHORRAIRE where o.CLIENT_ID == CLIENT_ID && o.HORRAIRE > new TimeSpan(The_Hour, 00/*minutes*/, 00/*seconds*/) select o;
```

Comment: You should add some more text to your answers